# Insert hyperlinks into PDF comments

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I'd like to write a comment inside a pdf document, linking to some other part of the same document (something like "see section 2.3"). As I'm not the author of the document, I am only allowed to write comments, not content.

I found [on adobe forum](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/300740) a workaround for inserting a URL link Inside a PDF comment, but nothing for an internal link (or a link to another file, which would be harder to manage).

That document already contains internal links inside its body, proving that link targets exist.

I am using adobe reader 11.0.19 but I'm willing to change if needed.